# Keep image size as a percentage of the screen the same when zooming in

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to get an image to stay the same size (relative to the window) when zooming in, this means that when zooming in the images will appear to not change size at all (but really they will be reducing in size). I manage to do it with text by using the 'vh' units but this doesn't work with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use actual percentages when defining your images width, like so:

## HTML

```
<img src="yourimage.png" class="imageThingy">
```

## CSS

```
.imageThingy{
    width: 50%;
}
```

This will preserve the image size when zooming in on a window.

Comment: No problem! Have fun :D

Comment: @DominicNewman can you accept his answer if it was helpful please? thank you :)